# Define color for chapter in scrbook

Tags: color

I try to change the color of my chapter heading:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{myColor_MainA}{RGB}{0,64,119}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{myColor_MainA}}
% \addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{myColor_MainA}}

\begin{document}
 \chapter{first}
 \section{here}
\end{document}
```

and get following error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.8  \chapter{first}

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\size@chapter ->\huge \color {myColor_MainA}

l.8  \chapter{first}

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.8  \chapter{first}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.8  \chapter{first}
```

Comment: Remove the underscore `_` from the color name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in KOMA-Script (2015/07/02 v3.18). The chapter uses the command `\usefontofcomafont{chapter}` which disables the color commands by assigning `\color` to `\relax`. This way, the argument of `\color` remains and the underscore in the name is typeset as text, causing trouble, because `_` is not in math mode.

Workarounds:

- A color name, which is can be processed in text mode without error
  (without underscore, see nordev's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262347/define-color-for-chapter-in-scrbook#comment629165_262347)).
- `\string` before the underscore also fixes the issue. The color name remains valid (the name is used inside `\csname` and `\endcsname`), and the name can be processed in text typesetting mode.

  ```
  \addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{myColor\string_MainA}}
  ```

Comment: Markus Kohm already answered that he expects this issue fixed in the next version of KOMA-Script.